# How to speed up the code for LeetCode "Container with most water" task?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-limit-exceeded

I'm trying to solve the LeetCode question where you need to find out the area of the [container with the most water](https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/). I have created the solution that seems to work in my testing but it fails for being too slow when I try to submit it on LeetCode.

My idea is that I create a dictionary of (x, y) tuples from the input list and then for every item I need to find the maximum distance to any of other lines that are equal or taller than it and from here I can calculate what the maximum area is possible for this line.

How else can I approach this to get it to run faster? (I can't submit solution successfully so can't see examples of answers by other users)

```
def max_area(height) -> int:
    areas = []
    coords = {x: (x, y) for x, y in enumerate(height)}
    for x in coords:
        higher = [k for k in coords if coords[k][1] >= coords[x][1]]
        area = max(abs(coords[j][0] - coords[x][0]) for j in higher) * coords[x][1]
        areas.append(area)
    return max(areas)
```

Comment: Hello, to give a more detailed a more specific description of the problem you can add the `time-limit-exceeded` tag to your question.

Comment: *"can't see examples of answers by other users"* - Are you sure you're telling the truth? I can see [other people's solutions](https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=) even when not logged in at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question made me want to give it a shot, too. The solution ended up pretty much like the pseudo-code suggested by @Marc , and Python is of course pretty close in readability anyway. The below code passes on the site and runs (there is some deviation between runs) **faster than c. 95%** and at with less memory usage than c. **75%** of solutions. The code contains comments at the relevant positions. There's two extra optimizations, also explained there.

```py
def max_area(height: list[int]) -> int:
        n = len(height) - 1
        l = 0  # Index for left bar
        r = n  # Index for right bar
        max_area = 0

        while True:
            # Give readable names:
            left = height[l]
            right = height[r]

            # Current area, constrained by lower bar:
            area = min(left, right) * (r - l)
            if area > max_area:
                # Keep tabs on maximum, the task doesn't ask for any
                # more details than that.
                max_area = area

            # Move the smaller bar further inwards towards the center, expressed
            # as moving left, where *not* moving left implies moving right.
            # The smaller bar constrains the area, and we hope to get to a longer
            # one by moving inwards, at which point the other bar forms the constraint,
            # so the entire thing reverses.
            move_left = left < right

            # Instead of only moving the smaller bar inward by one step, there's two
            # extra steps here:
            #    1. While moving the smaller bar inward, skip all bars that are
            #       *even smaller*; those are definitely not the target, since both
            #       their height and horizontal delta will be smaller.
            #    2. While skipping all smaller bars, we might hit the other bar:
            #       there is a 'valley' or at least nothing higher in between.
            #       Any more moving inwards would be a wasted effort, no matter the
            #       the direction (from left or right). We can return the current
            #       max. area.
            #
            # In the best case scenario, this may skip us right to the solution,
            # e.g. for `[10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10]`: only one outer loop is necessary.
            #
            # Both loops look very similar, maybe there's room for some indirection
            # here, although a function call would probably mess with the raw
            # performance.
            if move_left:
                while height[l] <= left:
                    if l == r:
                        return max_area
                    l += 1
            else:
                while height[r] <= right:
                    if r == l:
                        return max_area
                    r -= 1


# Examples from the site
print(max_area([1, 8, 6, 2, 5, 4, 8, 3, 7]) == 49)
print(max_area([2, 3, 10, 5, 7, 8, 9]) == 36)
print(max_area([1, 3, 2, 5, 25, 24, 5]) == 24)
```

---

As far as your code goes:

- The mapping

  ```py
  coords = {x: (x, y) for x, y in enumerate(height)}
  ```

  seems pretty odd. You're kind of mapping `x` to itself. I would say for the solution it's much simpler to not treat `x` as `x` in the "2D math plot" sense, but just as `i` in the array index sense. This saves us having to even declare `x`, we can just iterate using `i`.
- You use `max` twice, which is a linear search operation each time. This is needlessly expensive, but probably not the bottleneck.
- Any algorithm based on finding e.g. *all distances to every other item* for *every* item has explosive complexity. This is likely the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion about your current solution:

```
def max_area(height) -> int:
    areas = []
    coords = {x: (x, y) for x, y in enumerate(height)}
    for x in coords:
        higher = [k for k in coords if coords[k][1] >= coords[x][1]]
        area = max(abs(coords[j][0] - coords[x][0]) for j in higher) * coords[x][1]
        areas.append(area)
    return max(areas)
```

- Keep track of the biggest area so far, instead of using the list `areas`.

```
def max_area(height) -> int:
    coords = {x: (x, y) for x, y in enumerate(height)}
    result = 0
    for x in coords:
        higher = [k for k in coords if coords[k][1] >= coords[x][1]]
        area = max(abs(coords[j][0] - coords[x][0]) for j in higher) * coords[x][1]
        result = max(result, area)
    return result
```

This reduces memory usage but is not enough to pass the challenge.

The solution can be considered a brute force approach which is typically not enough to solve medium/hard problems on LeetCode.

The constraint is \$n <= 3 * 10^4\$, where \$n\$ is the length of the input list. Generally, with such constraint, we should look at a solution with a time complexity less than \$O(n^2)\$.

Let's consider the example on LeetCode where the input list is:

- height = [1,8,6,2,5,4,8,3,7]

[image]

For each two bars, the biggest area is given by the lowest bar. In the example, the two bars are `8` and `7`, so the area is `7 * (8 - 1) = 49`. Note that `(8 - 1)` is the difference between the indices of the bars. This is an \$O(n)\$ algorithm:

```
Initialize l to 0
Initialize r to the right most index
Initialize max_area to 0
while l is lower than r
    find the area as: lowest bar * (r - l)
    update max_area
    increment l if points to the lower bar, else decrement r
return max_area
```

Next time you can check the "hints" and the tab "Discuss" for help or alternative solutions.